# SVG Below DIV Reacting to Events

Tags: html, css, svg, event-handling, overlay

Guess you have an `<svg id='chart'>` taking over the all `<div id='main'>`, that takes over the all page.

Now inside that `<div>` there is also another `<div id='tab'>` with `poisition: absolute;`.

How do I make it so that when the mouse passes underneath the `#tab` the path elements in the `#chart` svg are still reacting to their events rather than being obstructed from the (semi-transparent) `#tab` element?

Answer (score 0):

disabling events on the `#tab` solves it.

```css
#tab {
    pointer-events: none;
}
```